# GitLab: include branches from a similar project to local repo

Tags: gitlab

i am pretty new to GitLab and have a question concerning branches and updating the local repo.
Around two weeks ago i cloned a project and did a bit of work on it (mainly added one branch). Other people also have local repositories of that same project (hope that makes sense). Now I would like to clone only a single branch of one of those local repos made by other people and include it into my local repo.... How do i do this? Ofc I can clone the branch into a different directory, but my goal is only having one directory with only one name in which that branch is contained, so that I can switch between the branches I had from the beginning and the new branch I cloned.

Basically, in order to be more clear: There is a project called a_proj. Me and another person have cloned a_proj and therefore have local repos on which we do work. The other person added a branch called a_branch which I don't have. I want to include a_branch into my version of a_proj.

Additionally i have a different question concerning updating a branch. What if some person does some work on their local version of a branch I also have on my Local and I want to include their changes, or even change my branch to their version. How could I do that?

Thank you a lot for any helpful answers on this topic. If there is constructive critic about this post or the way I think about GitLab I am happy to hear it, as already mentioned, this is a pretty new topic to me and I want to learn wherever i can!

Comment: An idea I have would be: cloning the other person's repo into a new temp. directory.  Check out the branch I want to have. Copy the directory contents. Make a new branch in my local repo. Insert the directory contents and use all changes, delete the clone in the temp directory.... however, to me that seems wrong somehow

Answer (score 0):

Okay, i figured it out. Was pretty easy actually once one knows what to do. For information, i am using GitKraken so it might be different for different environments but essentially the idea is to add the other person's project as remote, (where ones own project should also be a remote named origin). Then one can add any branch of those remotes to the Local project, simply by checking out the wanted branch. It then gets added to the Local repository on which work can be done.
I guess that isn't anything new to anybody who uses GitLab but i'll just leave it here in case some noob (Like me) also has this question.